# Chromium - Using apple script to open URL

Tags: applescript, chromium

I create a game using html5 based on Chromium project (in Mac). In order to open the game in Chromium, select File menu and select the Open file and browse for the html. And the game is working fine this way 
I want to write some script that opens the html in Chromium browser so that I can package it as an application and distribute it as DMG. Has any one come across Chromium script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set myFile to "/Users/Satyam/Desktop/OriginalMsg.htm"
do shell script "open " & quoted form of myFile & " -a Chromium"
```

EDIT

```
set myFile to "/Users/Satyam/Desktop/OriginalMsg.htm"
do shell script "open " & quoted form of myFile & " -a Chromium"

tell application "Chromium"
    activate
    close (every tab of window 1 whose title = "New Tab")
end tell
```

Comment: Its good. But its showing 2 tabs. Can we restrict it to open in one tab only? How can I see the dictionary/options of Chromium? In Mac OSX 10.4.x, we can open any application in Dictionary application which lists all the options that we can handle with script editor. In Lion/Mountain Lion, I dont know any such option

Comment: It is a bit hacky, but see my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to open a url specifically in Chromium. However, normally you do it this way and it will open in a users default web browser. This is the normal way to open files, you don't target a specific application but you let it open in the users' preference.

Maybe it will help you. Good luck.

```
open location "http://www.url.com"
```